# PHP DOM in WordPress - replace and add attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I try to change `type` attribute of input fields to `number` (they have `hidden` type by default) and add `readonly="readonly"`, but it has no effect on output HTML. Attributes are as they were.

Function is triggered properly, because before I added encoding, it showed incorrect characters on page. I have proper CSS to format readonly inputs, so visuals are not a problem, I will also use more conditions to find only specific input tags, but for now I would like to get this code to work properly:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'acau_lock_input');
function acau_lock_input($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();       
    @$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('input') as $node) {            
        $node->setAttribute('type', 'number');
        $node->setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
    $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
    return $newHtml;
}
```

Comment: Try setting attributes with ", instead of '?

Comment: Would be interested to see why you think this will make any difference?

Comment: I would discourage the use of `@` as it can cover up problems, can you show an example of what `$content` may contain (not sure how to get this though).

Comment: It didn't make any difference in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nigel Ren helped me to find the problem. The solution is ridiculous, `the_content` filter of WordPress is simply whatever is placed in the text area of the current page as visible in the editor.

It has nothing to do with full HTML structure of output page, so while wrong encoding can break text of the whole page, `$content` returns only one shortcode because this is in the page editor.

To learn how to edit DOM for WordPress, including the output of all templates, check this question:

[PHP DOM in WordPress - add attribute in output buffer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317473/php-dom-in-wordpress-add-attribute-in-output-buffer-html/56348066#56348066)